# on Sendbird How to fetch all the rooms in open chat message?

Tags: sendbird

We are looking at this api.

https://api.sendbird.com/admin/list_messaging_channels

with our payload:

```
{
  "auth": APP_TOKEN,
  "id": userid,
}
```

but the response is always.

> [0]

is there something else we missed with the api?

We can't find something we can use to display all the previous chat channels with previous message in it. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. You have been trying to get messaging channels not open chat channels via Server API.
Serve API only supports reading and getting messaging channels for now but 
we're working on new REST API which will support open chat channels as well. It should be released by the end of this month.